# how to remove html tags from a rss feed xml file . i'm using DOM parser in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, dom, xml-parsing, rss

im trying to get rss feeds with dom parser and im not getting the description tag from the xml file because it contains some html tags.

How to parse the text from the description tag ?